# chmod/chown after every svn update necessary

Tags: svn

I use CentOS 5.5, and SVN 1.4.2

I use a working copy on my server as my webapplication, so that I can easily deploy the new code. But what really bothers me, is the fact, that every time I do an `svn up` (or `svn update`) I have to reset the file permission.

How can I solve that? I actually don't like to create an svn post-commit-hook. Is there any way to tell CentOS that newly added/changed files within certain files should always have certain permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with file acl (facl)? You can set default permissions for the new files in a folder.

```
#set acl for a file: 
setfacl -m u:Usuario:rwx filex
#set default acl for new files in directory
setfacl -dm u:usuario:rmx directory
```

Use -R option for recursive setfacl.

Comment: +1, also a reminder that many filesystems will need to be mounted with ACL support enable, which is done by adding "acl" to the options list in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Thanks, but he gives me the following:
-bash: setfacl: command not found

Comment: CentOS/RedHad generally install acl package by default but if it doesnt you can install it from yum using: `yum install acl` as root

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to do this is via a post-commit hook. Here are the ones I use:

http://code.getbunch.com/svn-hooks-for-staging-servers/

Basically, you need to install them in the hooks/ directory in your repo. Add the following to your post-commit (after line 27) to make your changes:

```
# Make sure ownership and permissions are correct is correct
chown myuser.mygroup -R $DIR_TO_TEST_VHOST
chmod 777 -R $DIR_TO_TEST_VHOST
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

`svn propset svn:executable ON filename.php`

or use CornerStone
[file property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDZ2d.jpg)